# Liquibase changelog parameters in liquibase.properties

Tags: liquibase

As per documentation parameter values are looked up in the following order:

Passed as a parameter to your Liquibase runner (see Ant, command_line, etc. documentation for how to pass them)

As a JVM system property

In the parameters block ( Tag) of the DatabaseChangeLog file itself.

Can I set these parameters in the standard properties file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It is possible** to put changelog parameters in liquibase.properties, or a custom --defaultsFile.  [Reading the source](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3202b3509ec127a94dc5f767bd5dd4a16c4ee06b/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#L459-L460) indicates that you must **prefix the properties with "parameter."**.

Your error probably looks something like this:

```
SEVERE 11/4/16 10:26 AM: liquibase: Unknown parameter: 'read_only_user'
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: Unknown parameter: 'read_only_user'
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.parsePropertiesFile(Main.java:453)
```

Example liquibase.properties:

```
driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbhost)(PORT=1600))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=devdb)))"
username=scott
password=tiger
defaultSchemaName=app_admin
promptOnNonLocalDatabase=false
parameter.read_only_user=app_read
```

Using the parameter in a changeset:

```
<changeset author="Ryan" id="1">
  <sql>GRANT SELECT ON APP.SOME_TABLE TO ${read_only_user}</sql>
</changeset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and is very usefull if you want to manage information under control...like passwords in differents enviroments:
liquibase.properties:

```
parameter.pass_admin=idonthavepassword
```

and the changelog:

```
<changeSet author="rbs" id="create_user_admin" labels="inicial">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='admin'</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <sql>CREATE USER admin PASSWORD '${pass_admin}' LOGIN SUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT NOREPLICATION CONNECTION LIMIT -1
        <comment>Creating admin user</comment>
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/liquibase.properties.html. 
And use --defaultsFile to pass property file.

Comment: Question is - what to put in the properties file for changelog parameters?

Comment: eg. changelog parameter is ${user_name}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a sql like create table ${user_name}.ak(id number)and I am trying to set the value of  ${user_name} in the properties file. I can set it using the command line argument liquibase update -Duser_name=test_schema but want to know if setting the same in properties file is possible.

Comment: According too this page http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html it should be something like ${user_name} in your changelog and user_name=user1 in property file.