# Liquibase Parameters not being read correctly in changelog

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am attempting to get some parameters from `liquibase.properties` read into my changelog file but not having much success.

I am basing my work on the following stack overflow question: [Liquibase changelog parameters in liquibase.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915229/liquibase-changelog-parameters-in-liquibase-properties)

The following is my liquibase.properties file:

```
driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
changeLogFile:src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localDB
username:root
password:superSecretPassword
verbose:true
parameter.schemaName:dev_tableName
```

I have a few different liquibase.properties files for different profiles on maven. The following is in my changelog file and the part I am having difficulty with.

```
<property name="schema" value='${schemaName}' />
```

The problem is the property is always coming back as the literal value "${schemaName}" and not "dev_tableName". The reason I need this is because there is a reference to another schema in my changelog that changes from environment to environment.

For example dev_tableName and sys_tableName, and I would rather have several liquibase.properties files for each environment as opposed to a full set of changelogs for each environment. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

If it matters- I am building this via Maven with the following settings:

```
<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>${liquibase.properties.path}</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>update</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java/</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.hibernate.HibernateAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <liquibase.properties.path>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/dev/liquibase.properties</liquibase.properties.path>
            <env>dev</env>
            <versionNumber>${env}-${project.version}</versionNumber>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: PUtting the parameter into the .properties file works for. But you can also pass them on the command line: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html#update-passing-changelog-parameters

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, I know the command line can also take commands but I would prefer to have it done via the properties files, any idea why the above is not working? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use two properties? Why not simply use `${schemaName}` directly instead of `${schema}`?

Comment: Its just a way to illustrate the problem, I am using the following, <addForeignKeyConstraint .... referencedTableCatalogName="${schemaName}". that does not work either - The issue is that the parameter is not being read.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem I ended up solving this issue by using Maven resource plugin instead. Link can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html